# How can I reference a value from a serialised string in AMPscript for Email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

I have a transactional Journey, which is triggered by API and sends a personalised email.

The email AMPscript uses two DEs, which have a common field "sku", so I'm using it as AttributeValue. However, "sku" field is inside "orderItems" in DE_1 as a serialised string.

Here is how the fields look in postman:

```
"attributes": {
        "orderNumber": "string",
        "firstName": "string",
        "lastName": "string",
        "shippingAmount": 56789,
        "taxationRatio": 56789,
        "orderUrl": "string",
        "orderedDate": "string",
        "orderItems": "[{\"sku\":\"123456\",\"quantity\":\"123456\",\"totalAmount\":\"56789\"}]"
```

Here is AMPscript from email:

```
set @sku = AttributeValue("sku")
set @rows = LookupRows("DE_2","sku", @sku)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
```

Is there any way to make AMPscript pull the "sku" value from the "orderItems" field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you would use the new AMPscript function, **[BuildRowsetFromJSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/buildrowsetfromjson.html)**

I am assuming DE_1 is the 'sendable' data extension, so to access the field that it is sitting in, we will do an attributevalue on that field name in the DE.

```ampscript
set @orderItems = AttributeValue("orderItems")
```

We then would need to use BuildRowsetFromJSON to break down this JSON array so we can use the information inside of it.

```ampscript
set @jsonRS = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@orderItems,'$.[*].sku',1)
```

(I set it to only grab the sku value for easy return, but you can get rid of the `.sku` at the end of the JSONpathing if you want all the info in it.

then from there we will want to pull out the row we need:

```ampscript
set @row = Row(@jsonRS,1)
```

and then we grab the field from the row:

```ampscript
set @sku = Field(@row,1)
```

You can then use that to do the lookup you need.

End code will look something like:

```ampscript
set @orderItems = AttributeValue("orderItems")
set @jsonRS = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@orderItems,'$.[*].sku',1)
set @row = Row(@jsonRS,1)
set @sku = Field(@row,1)
set @rows = LookupRows("DE_2","sku", @sku)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!